# The VM can ping the host machine, but can not ping other public IP

Tags: openstack

I in a remote Server (I call it `host machine`) setup the OpenStack Ocata. 
And in the OpenStack Ocata I created a VM, the VM use the Security Group (named `allow ping & ssh`), which is created by myself:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Now, I can use my Mac ping the VM. but can not ssh connect to the VM.

And in the VM(it's IP is `192.168.1.4` and floating IP is `103.35.202.3`), I can ping `192.168.1.1` and `103.35.202.1`(the host machine's public IP), but can not ping `google.com` or other public IP.

1. Why in my Mac I can ping the VM but can not ssh to it?
2. Why in the VM I can ping the host machine, but can not ping other public IP?

where is the issue?

Comment: Try adding Egress for TCP and then test it out again.

Comment: @MichaelPetersen Still can not ping `google.com` or other public ip.

Comment: Egress for testing SSH. You may want to enable UDP so that you can perform external DNS lookups. Try setting up Egress for ICMP/TCP/UDP, then see if you can resolve + ping from the VM. Also you can test SSH again.

Comment: @MichaelPetersen Still can not access.

Comment: Are you trying to SSH to the instance? Maybe try `ssh -v` to see if there are issues other than networking. If you can ping it - then you may be able to SSH to it as long as the TCP rules are configured.

Comment: @MichaelPetersen Yes, I can use ssh to connect the instance now. but in the instance I can not ping `google.com`

Comment: Can you resolve google.com? Did you try pinging 8.8.8.8? Are you able to hit the DNS servers setup for your network? You could test DNS resolution with `host google.com`

Comment: @MichaelPetersen I can ping the `8.8.8.8`, and I can ping `216.58.200.238`(this is google's ip), but can not ping `google.com`.

Comment: It sounds like you are having issues with DNS resolution then. See which DNS servers you are using, verify that you can reach them.

Comment: @MichaelPetersen How to check it my friend?

Comment: @MichaelPetersen You can answer my post now, you solved most of the question. thank you , my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the only Egress traffic allowed out is for ICMP. Egress is missing for TCP/UDP. Add in Egress rules for both UDP (should help resolve the DNS issue) and TCP (should resolve the SSH issue.)

After adding in the Egress rules for TCP - test ssh again.

After adding in the Egress rules for UDP - test DNS resolution, if you are still running into issues then you may want to verify the DNS servers used when configuring the network.